# Use grafana variable dependency from other variable selection (with prometheus)

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I'm using Grafana to show Prometheus metrics. I have two variables in grafana, one is querying a `label_values(kubernetes_name)`.

I want to create another variable which will provide ***instance*** label values, but I do not want to get all the values of this ***instance*** label, I want only those which came from a metrics that has kubernetes_name=$kubernetes_name where $kubernetes_name is coming from the first variable.

Basically, I want to be able to run this label_values:

```
label_values(instance)
```

only if those came from a metrics which had label

```
kubernetes_name = $kubernetes_name
```

I'm not even sure I can do values dependency like this, I couldn't find it in the docs :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first variable use the following query:

```
label_values(kubernetes_name)
```

In the second variable use the following query:

```
label_values({kubernetes_name="$kubernetes_name"}, instance)
```

Comment: Nice... is there any documentation about this? I'm searching for a good place to read more about those options ;)

Comment: I didn't find exactly this in the documentation, the closer I found is here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable